# development in accuracy or to accuracy

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I wonder which one is correct:

> A introduces further developments in the accuracy of the model.

or

> A introduces further developments to the accuracy of the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think either is acceptable. I might lean towards the second example, but there is nothing technically wrong with the first one.

If you wanted to be extremely pedantic, one might say that, when introducing humans, you introduce one human ***to*** another. If you introduced one person ***in*** another, it makes no sense (or conveys an unfortunate implication that is probably best avoided), so the reader might be more accustomed to hearing 'to'. But, again, I don't think it is a hard rule whatsoever when talking about inanimate objects where placing one thing ***in*** another is literally or figuratively possible.